# Why cassandra-topology.properties "should be exactly the same on every node in the cluster"?

Tags: cassandra, ip, datastax

According to the Datastax documentation, for PropertyFileSnitch, this property file: cassandra-topology.properties "should be exactly the same on every node in the cluster" ([Datastax Documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/architecture/archSnitchPFSnitch.html))

Why is it so and is this requirement really strict?

*Context*:  I would like to be able to provide different IPs for the same target node, depending on where the calling node (with the property file) is located. This is needed because of a complicated hybrid cloud/onpremise cluster and I want to avoid static **public** IPs.

Answer (score 1):

This snitch gives you more control and better performance.

The nodes that are not identified here will be assumed to be in the default dc and rack.

Pleease note these explanations from the "Cassandra: The Definitive Guide", by Jeff Carpenter & Eben Hewitt, O'Reilly, June 2016, 2nd edition, p.138  regarding this matter.

> Update the values in this file to record each node in your cluster to
>   specify which rack contains the node with that IP and which data
>   center it’s in. Although this may seem difficult to maintain if you
>   expect to add or remove nodes with some frequency, remember that it’s
>   one alternative, and it trades away a little flexibility and ease of
>   maintenance in order to give you more control and better runtime
>   performance, as Cassandra doesn’t have to figure out where nodes are.
>   Instead, you just tell it where they are.

Comment: Yes, I am exactly after the more control, but because of network peculiarities (hybrid cloud/on-premise cluster), I would like to be able to provide different IPs for the same node, depending on where the node (with the property file) is located. This would inherently mean that the the  cassandra-topology.propertiesis is going to be different in the different networks. And Datastax says "no". But why?